# RSpec 2 speccing a static ActiveRecord method

Tags: ruby, rspec2

I've got a pretty basic static method on an ActiveRecord model:

```
#./app/models/comic.rb
class Comic < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    def furthest
      Comic.maximum(:comic_id) || 0
    end
  end
end
```

When executing `Comic.furthest` in the Rails console it returns 0 as I expect.  The problem is I am trying to spec this behavior for both the presence and absence of records:

```
#./spec/app/models/comic_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Comic do
  describe "#furthest" do
    subject { Comic.furthest }

    context "when there are no rows in the database" do
      it { should == 0 }
    end

    context "when there are rows in the database" do
      before do
        Factory.create(:comic, :comic_id => 100)
        Factory.create(:comic, :comic_id => 99)
      end

      it { should == 100 }
    end
  end
end
```

All of this appears very basic and straightforward, however my specs are failing with the message:

```
1) Comic#furthest when there are no rows in the database 
 Failure/Error: it { should == 0 }
   expected: 0
        got: nil (using ==)
 # ./spec/models/comic_spec.rb:8:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Even if I change `furthest` to simply:

```
def furthest
  0
end
```

I still get `nil (using ==)`.

The second spec, `it { should == 100 }` passes with the original `Comic.maximum(:comic_id) || 0` definition, as if the `Factory.create` invocations are required for `#furthest` to not return `nil`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried defining furthest as --- 0 unless Comic.maximum(:comic_id) ?

Comment: It all looks logical to me. If you output the value of `subject`, is it what you expect? And for a quick sanity check, if you change the example to `Comic.furthest.should == 0`, does it make a difference?

Comment: I have now tried `0 unless Comic.maximum(:comic_id)` with no change in behavior.

Comment: I have added `puts "subject is #{subject}";` to both of my `it { ... }` blocks, for the failing block subject is nil and for the passing block subject is 100.

Comment: Also interesting: I am `tail -f ./log/test.log` and seeing the statement `SELECT MAX("comics"."comic_id") AS max_id FROM "comics"` being executed for each invocation of `#furthest`.

Comment: What version of Rails and RSpec are you using? What database for the test environment? I just created a fresh Rails 3.0.9 project, added your model and specs, and they both run fine.

Comment: Rails 3.0.9, RSpec 2.6.4, ruby-1.9.2 with the file loading performance patch hack.  I will try it on ruby-1.9.2 instead of my patched version and see if that corrects the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fairly confident this was a problem with me using the p180 release of Ruby 1.9.2 with custom patches to improve require performance.  After upgrading to p290 this problem is gone.